# Inside a try block should only be the instructions that could throw the exception or can put some code not relevant for the exception?

Tags: coding-style, try-catch

If i know that only one function (take in the example) will throw the exception, what could be the correct way, of the following options?

1. All in the try block:

   ```
   try
   {
       while (someCondition)
       {
           take();   
           anotherFunction();
       }
   }
   catch(Exceotion e)
   {
       //some instructions
   }
   ```
2. Inside the block only the function that throw the exception:

   ```
   while (someCondition)
       {
           try
           { 
               take();   
           }
           catch....
           {
                //some instructions
           }
           anotherFunction();
       }
   ```

I would use the first way because it's clearer, but there is an explicit rule about this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two ways do *very* different things and depending on what you need the code to do, either can be correct.

In the first example, `anotherFunction` is not called if there was an exception.

In the second example, the exception is being dealt with in the `catch` block, and `anotherFunction` will be executed afterwards.

Along the same lines, in the first example, an exception aborts the whole `while` loop, whereas in the second example it aborts only a single iteration and continues the loop with the next iteration.